# dplyr lag passing vector instead of single value to invoked function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this one:

```
> df
  threadId          threadTime
1        1 2014-07-08 18:28:29
2        1 2014-07-08 18:46:09
3        2 2014-07-10 10:14:42
4        2 2014-07-10 10:30:49
5        3 2014-07-10 11:19:27
6        3 2014-07-10 11:45:23
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ threadId  : num  1 1 2 2 3 3
 $ threadTime: POSIXct, format: "2014-07-08 18:28:29" "2014-07-08 18:46:09" ...
```

I am using a simple function call (it does not matter what this function does):

```
someFunc <- function(t1, t2) { cat(t1); cat('\n'); return(1)}
```

When I invoke the function to mutate a new column on the data frame as follows, I see that the function is invoked with a vector of threadTime values instead of the value of the lagged row and current row independently. What am I missing?

```
df %>% group_by(threadId) %>% mutate(blah = someFunc(lag(threadTime), threadTime))
```

I was expecting t1 to be time in the lagged row, and t2 to be the time in the current row. Of course, the first row of the group will have NA for lagged value, and I am fine and can check for that in my function.

Output from that function invocation for the 'three groups in the df' are as follows for just the t1 parameter. The function gets invoked with the concatenated values of 'lag(threadTime)' and also the 'threadTime'.

```
t1 = NA 1404858509
t1 = NA 1405001682
t1 = NA 1405005567
```

#### UPDATE

Turns out that what my function does/needs matters entirely. Updating the question. I want to calculate working days and hours between lagged row time values. So, I am using a function as follows (onDays are business days, net of weekends + holidays, and onHours are business hours):

```
workingHours <- function(t1, t2) {
  elapsedTime <- seq.POSIXt(from = t1, to = t2, by = 'hour')
  elapsedTime <- elapsedTime[as.Date(elapsedTime) %in% onDays &
                               as.numeric(format(elapsedTime, '%H')) %in%
                               onHours]
  return(length(elapsedTime))
}
```

In this case, seq.POSIXt won't take vectors for 'from' and 'to' and so I can't use vectorized lag() values. Is there a better alternative than 'looping' or using some sort of an apply() call that is perhaps only a slight improvement over a loop?

Comment: This update came fairly late---I don't have a ready answer and I doubt other eyes are on this question. I'd recommend deleting the update and asking a new question that doesn't have all the unrelated stuff at the top and just focuses on your elapsed time question.

Comment: That said, I think the original answer jeremycg posted to this question could work (or some variant of it). If you just add a lagged column with a regular `mutate`, I *think* you can use `rowwise` and your function to get the answer. I'm just not sure. (An example of expected output would help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm posting as an answer...

Your general `lag()` syntax should work. I would check that you don't have a masking issue going on, several other packages provided `lag` functions that are different from dplyr's. You can always be explicit and call `dplyr::lag` to be sure.

Here's some code on built-in data to demonstrate that your basic idea *should* work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  arrange(cyl, mpg) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mpgmpg = paste(lag(mpg), mpg, sep = "!"))

# Source: local data frame [32 x 12]
# Groups: cyl
#
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    mpgmpg
# 1  21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2   NA!21.4
# 2  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 21.4!21.5
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 21.5!22.8
# 4  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 22.8!22.8
# 5  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 22.8!24.4
# 6  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2   24.4!26
```

Similarly, using a modified version of your function:

```
someFunc <- function(t1, t2) { cat(t1); cat("\n"); cat(t2); cat('\n\n'); return(1)}
```

This is what I would expect, and what I get:

```
mtcars %>% arrange(cyl, mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mpgmpg = someFunc(lag(mpg), mpg))
# NA 21.4 21.5 22.8 22.8 24.4 26 27.3 30.4 30.4 32.4
# 21.4 21.5 22.8 22.8 24.4 26 27.3 30.4 30.4 32.4 33.9

# NA 17.8 18.1 19.2 19.7 21 21
# 17.8 18.1 19.2 19.7 21 21 21.4

# NA 10.4 10.4 13.3 14.3 14.7 15 15.2 15.2 15.5 15.8 16.4 17.3 18.7
# 10.4 10.4 13.3 14.3 14.7 15 15.2 15.2 15.5 15.8 16.4 17.3 18.7 19.2
# ...
```

This is because `lag` is vectorized and `someFunc` is vectorized, which is a good thing! It seems to match your description:

> I was expecting t1 to be time in the lagged row, and t2 to be the time in the current row

You can see how the lagged values (top rows) are paired with the current values (bottom rows).

If this isn't what you want, please edit your question to show the *desired behavior*, preferably on a built-in data set or an a `dput()` or simulated data.

Comment: Oh my god, I did not even realize that the vectorized implementation makes this all efficient and such, and it is by design. My need is slightly different. I will update the question.